# Observable FromEventPattern when object rasing events is reinstantiated

Tags: system.reactive

I am trying to set up an observable in a class that will tick each time an event fires on a member.

```
public class FooService
{

  private BarProvider _barProvider;
  public IObservable<BarChangedEventArgs> BarChanged { get; }

  public FooService()
  {        
    BarChanged = 
      Observable
        .FromEventPattern<BarChangedHandler, BarChangedEventArgs>(
          h => _barProvider.Changed += h,
          h => _barProvider.Changed -= h)
        .Select(p => p.EventArgs);
  }

  public void OccursSomeTimeAfterFooServiceCreation
  (
    Func<BarProvider> barProviderFactory
  )
  {
    _barProvider = barProviderFactory();
  }
}
```

What I think I need to do is set up the event handler observable after assigning the new value of _barProvider in the OccursLater method, as this is a new event source. However, I believe setting BarChanged at this later point, after consumers may have already subscribed, will break those existing subscriptions.

I would like consumers of the FooService to be able to subscribe to BarChanged at any point, and see the observable as one stream of event args, regardless of how many times OccursSomeTimeAfterFooServiceCreation is called after the subscription is created.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Observable - creation depends on stuff that can change e.g. your barProvider, you should always retrieve those from other Observables and then utilize the Switch() operator.

To achieve this I utilized the BehaviorSubject.

```
    public class FooService
    {
        public BehaviorSubject<BarProvider> _barProviderSubject = new BehaviorSubject<BarProvider>(null); //or initialize this subject with the barprovider of your choice

        public IObservable<BarChangedEventArgs> BarChanged { get; }

        public FooService()
        {
            var barChangedChanged = _barProviderSubject.Where(bP => bP != null).Select(bP =>
                Observable.FromEventPattern<BarChangedHandler, BarChangedEventArgs>(
                        h => bP.Changed += h,
                        h => bP.Changed -= h)
                    .Select(p => p.EventArgs)
            );
            BarChanged = barChangedChanged.Switch();
        }

        public void OccursSomeTimeAfterFooServiceCreation
        (
            Func<BarProvider> barProviderFactory
        )
        {
            _barProviderSubject.OnNext(barProviderFactory());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer I accepted because it appears to be working. I believe the .Select(subject) should be .Subscribe, making it so the subject acts as observer for each _barProvider's event. That subject is exposed through BarChanged => subject.AsObservable();

Comment: I actually updated my code to use the BehaviorSubject. My initial thought was that I should be somehow picking up the barProvider change in an observable but wasn't sure how to do that. This addresses exactly that with a tool designed for monitoring this sort of change over time. Going to change this to my accepted answer for this problem.

Comment: A [Subject<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229173) is both and `IObservable<T>` that you can subscribe to and an `IObserver<T>` that can subscribe to any observable.

Comment: Oh, I get it! There were "a few characters" "missing". :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't observe classes or variables. You observe instances.

If I understand it correctly, you want your subscribers to be oblivious of the fact that the observed instance changes.

Try something like this:

```
public class FooService
{
  private BarProvider _barProvider;
  private Subject<BarChangedEventArgs> subject = new Subject<BarChangedEventArgs>();
  public IObservable<BarChangedEventArgs> BarChanged { get; } = subject.AsObservable();

  public FooService()
  {        
  }

  public void OccursSomeTimeAfterFooServiceCreation
  (
    Func<BarProvider> barProviderFactory
  )
  {
    _barProvider = barProviderFactory();

    BarChanged = 
      Observable
        .FromEventPattern<BarChangedHandler, BarChangedEventArgs>(
          h => _barProvider.Changed += h,
          h => _barProvider.Changed -= h)
        .Select(p => p.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(subject);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this approach. As opposed to reassigning BarChanged each time _barProvider changes, I have `public IObservable<BarChangedEventArgs> BarChanged => subject.AsObservable().` With this, I got rid of the BarChanged assignment when _barProvider is assigned. If I set BarChanged again to a new Observable instance, wouldn't that cause existing subscriptions to break still?

Comment: I don't think I get what you're saying.

Comment: What I mean is that I may have a class that consumes the FooService. I get my FooService instance through constructor injection, and subscribe to BarChanged in the constructor. Much later in the code I may call _fooService.OccursSomeTime... after the BarChanged subscription is set. I don't want the consuming class to have to subscribe to BarChanged again in this scenario, I want it to be handled internally by the FooService.

Comment: I didn't test your code exactly as written. In the OccursSomeTime function, BarChanged is being assigned again. It looks like after the edit it is trying to assign an IDisposable subscription to an IObservable<Args>. If we take away `BarChanged = ...` and just set up the subscription (how I adapted your answer) I'm concerned with how to handle disposing the subscriptions that are created each time. I feel like the BehaviorSubject handles this cleanly.